# RegExp and Node JS

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

It's not a question, simply an input to share my solution.
In my script I have  a regExp to replace url by blank character. In javascript this code works well but not in node js

```
var urlExp = new RegExp("(ht|f)tps?:\/\/\S*","gi");
var newString = myString.replace(urlExp, " ");
```

Every pattern, I tested works fine on https://regex101.com/#javascript.
After many test with different RegExp pattern, I still have same issue.
sometime the first url part is matched, sometine nothing matches.

Comment: @Wiktor It's not the same case ! I think it's particular to V8

Comment: You should always double backslashes inside a constructor notation. It is common in any JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is :

```
var urlExp = /(ht|f)tps?:\/\/\S*/gi;
var newString = myString.replace(urlExp, " ");
```

;)